# How to make a two-pages table with footnotes?

Tags: tables, footnotes, longtable

I have this big table occupying a whole page and I need to make it even bigger. It has some footnotes associated with it. I tried to use the longtable package but then the table disappears.

When using the code bellow my footnotes cover the page number. What can I do to have a two-pages table and maintain the footnotes?

```
    \newpage
    \begin{table} [H]
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth} 
\caption{Produtos e serviços disponíveis no mercado para prototipagem de PCIs}
\label{tab:mercado}
\begin{center}
\scalebox{0.7}{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |M{3.3cm}||M{3cm}|M{3cm}|M{3cm}| }
\hline
Produto/Serviço& Descrição&Fabricante &Custo\\
\hline

... %table body

\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

This is the code in wich I try to use the longpage package:

```
    \begin{longtable}{ |M{3.3cm}||M{3cm}|M{3cm}|M{3cm}| }
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth} 
    \caption{Produtos e serviços disponíveis no mercado para prototipagem de PCIs}\label{tab:mercado}\\
    ... %table body
    \end{minipage}
    \end{longtable}
```

Comment: you can use longtable, if it "disappeared" presumably ther ewas an error in the use but impossible to guess as you haven't shown that. Note that it is usually recommended never to use `\scalebox` on a table.

Comment: `longtable` had not to be inside `minipage` or `table` environments. for notes consider to use `threeparttable`.

Comment: @David Carlisle I added the code!

Comment: why have you a minipage inside the longtable? that puts your entire content into the first column of the first row of the table and the longtable only has one cell and one row then.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was using it to make the footnotes for elements inside the table! It was working fine with the table/tabular model

Comment: no you had the `minipage` _outside_ the tabular but you have put the minipage inside the longtable so it puts everything in the first (and only) cell in the table. longtable supports footnotes directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if the following table example can help you:

- it use `ltablex` and `threeparttablex` packages
- instead `\footnote` is used `tnote`, consequently notes are immediately after table
- column width are determined so, that the table is more compact (and consequently need less vertical space)
- removed are the most of `\hline`s
- for more vertical space between rows are used `\addlinespace` from `booktabs`, for rest of lines are used rules from this package

considering above your table (as was present in the first version of your question) become:

[image]

*mwe:*

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, ltablex, threeparttablex}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedLeft}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
\let\TPTrlap\relax
    \begin{TableNotes}\footnotesize
\item[a] In \euro,
\item[b] Valor do pedido mínimo por polegada quadrada, com 5 placas dupla face
\item[c] Valor do pedido mínimo por polegada quadrada, com 3 placas dupla face
\item[d] In R\$. Valor do pedido mínimo, com número variado de placas dispostas na dimensão máxima de \SI{10x10}{cm}
    \end{TableNotes}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}
                >{\itshape}R
                >{\hsize=1.5\hsize}R
                >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}R
                >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}L
                                @{\hspace{0.5\tabcolsep}}}
\caption{Produtos e serviços disponíveis no mercado para prototipagem de PCIs}
\label{tab:mercado} \\
    \midrule
\upshape Produto/Serviço    & Descrição & Fabricante & {\makecell[b]{Custo\\ (in US\$)}} \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{Produtos e serviços disponíveis no mercado para prototipagem de PCIs (cont.)}
\label{tab:mercado} \\
    \midrule
\upshape Produto/Serviço    & Descrição & Fabricante & {Custo (in US\$)} \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape continue on the next page}
\endfoot
    \midrule[1pt]
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
PCB Prototype Kit
        &   \textit{Kit} completo para prototipagem por processo fotográfico em pequena escala
            &   \textit{Kinsten} - China
                & 895,00    \\
    \addlinespace
Dragonfly 2020 Pro
        & Impressora \textit{3D} de PCIs, utilizando método aditivo através de ``pigmentos'' condutivos
            & \textit{Nano Dimension} - Israel
                &   100 000,00 - \par
                    250 000,00 ~~\\
    \addlinespace
V-One   & \textit{Plotter} para PCIs utilizando tinta condutiva de prata, além de
\textit{dispenser} de pasta de solda
            & \textit{Voltera} - Canadá
                &   3 500,00 \\
    \addlinespace
Voxel8  &   Impressora \textit{3D} multimaterial, que imprime eletrônicos e seus circuitos de forma fundida
            & \textit{Voxel8} - EUA
                &   9 000,00 \\
    \addlinespace
Prometheus
        &   Fresadora CNC
            & \textit{Zippy Robotics} - EUA
                & 1 800,00  \\
    \addlinespace
Desktop PCB Milling Machine
        &   Fresadora CNC
            &   \textit{Bantam Tools} - EUA
                &   3 200,00 \\
    \addlinespace
Vision ONE
        &   Fresadora CNC
            & \textit{Zen Toolworks} - EUA
                &   600,00  \\
    \addlinespace
PCB Lab &   Fresadora CNC, além de \textit{dispenser} de pasta de solda e colocação de componentes
            & \textit{Cirqoid} - Letônia
                &  2 000,00\tnote{1} \\
    \addlinespace
Prototyping service for PCB and PCBA
        &   Serviço de confecção e montagem de PCIs
            &   \textit{Seeedstudio} - China
                &   $\times$ 4,90\tnote{2} \\
    \addlinespace
Prototyping service for PCB
        &   Serviço de confecção de PCIs
            &   \textit{OSH Park} - EUA
                &   5,00\tnote{3}\\
    \addlinespace
Confecção de circuitos impressos
        &   Serviço de confecção de PCIs
            &   \textit{Mazza G-TEC} - Brasil
                &    25,00\tnote{4}\\
    \addlinespace
Confecção de circuitos impressos
        &   Serviço de confecção de PCIs
            &   \textit{TEC CI} - Brasil
                &   \\
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{ThreePartTable}
```

Comment: wow thank you so much! It's even better than I imagined

Comment: Dear @GraziellaBedenik, you are welcome.  happy tex-ing!

Answer (score 2):

See documentation of `xltabular` for repeating the header.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}m{#1}}

\begin{document} 
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth} {|>{\itshape}X||M{3cm}|M{3cm}|M{3cm}| }
\caption{Produtos e serviços disponíveis no mercado para prototipagem de PCIs}
\label{tab:mercado}\\
\hline
\upshape Produto/Serviço& Descrição&Fabricante &Custo\\
\hline
PCB Prototype Kit   & \textit{Kit} completo para prototipagem por processo 
fotográfico em pequena escala&\textit{Kinsten} - China& US\$895,00\\
\hline
Dragonfly 2020 Pro& Impressora \textit{3D} de PCIs, utilizando método aditivo  
através de ``pigmentos'' condutivos& \textit{Nano Dimension} - Israel& 
US\$100.000,00-250.000,00 \\
\hline
V-One &\textit{Plotter} para PCIs utilizando tinta condutiva de prata, além de 
\textit{dispenser} de pasta de solda & \textit{Voltera} - Canadá& US\$3.500,00 \\
\hline
Voxel8&Impressora \textit{3D} multimaterial, que imprime eletrônicos e seus 
circuitos de forma fundida & \textit{Voxel8} - EUA&US\$9.000,00 \\
\hline
Prometheus &Fresadora CNC & \textit{Zippy Robotics} - EUA & US\$1.800,00\\
\hline
Desktop PCB Milling Machine&Fresadora CNC  & \textit{Bantam Tools} - EUA & 
US\$3.200,00 \\
\hline
Vision ONE&Fresadora CNC  & \textit{Zen Toolworks} - EUA & US\$600,00\\
 \hline
PCB Lab &Fresadora CNC, além de \textit{dispenser} de pasta de solda e colocação 
de componentes& \textit{Cirqoid} - Letônia& \euro2.000,00 \\
\hline
Prototyping service for PCB and PCBA & Serviço de confecção e montagem de 
PCIs&\textit{Seeedstudio} - China & US\$4,90\footnote{Valor do pedido mínimo por polegada 
quadrada, com 5 placas dupla face}\\
\hline
Prototyping service for PCB & Serviço de confecção de PCIs &\textit{OSH Park} - 
EUA&US\$5,00\footnote{Valor do pedido mínimo por polegada quadrada, com 3 placas dupla 
face}\\
\hline
Confecção de circuitos impressos&Serviço de confecção de PCIs&\textit{Mazza G-TEC} - 
Brasil& R\$25,00\footnote{Valor do pedido mínimo, com número variado de placas dispostas 
na dimensão máxima de 10x10 cm}\\
\hline
Confecção de circuitos impressos&Serviço de confecção de PCIs&\textit{TEC CI} - Brasil&\\
\hline
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```